# Why VBA collection data type keep on all item last value I add if I use loop?

Tags: vba

I have this collection:

```
Public col As New Collection
```

And this class named "Class":

```
Dim Name As String

Dim Tests As New Collection

Public Sub SetName(x As String)
    Name = x
End Sub

Public Sub AddTest(x As String)
    Tests.Add x
End Sub

Public Function GetName() As String
    GetName = Name
End Function
```

I tried to add values in in collection:

```
For k = 1 To 10
    Dim temp As New cls
    temp.SetName CStr(k)
    col.Add temp
Next k
```

And when I print names of all items from collection:

```
For Each item In col
    Debug.Print (item.GetName)
Next
```

I have next output:

```
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
```

Why my output is not

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

??

Why it puts last value on each item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `Dim temp As New cls` - There are many pitfalls to the shortcut notation...

The above notation effectively only ever creates a single instance of the `cls` object, and you're adding 10 references to that *single* instance to your collection. Every iteration, you update the name, and so, at the end, all instances have the name "10".  If you paused it during the loop, you'd notice that when there is 1 item in the collection, the item name would be "1", and when there are 2 items, all the names would be "2", and so on...

Declare the variable, and then set the variable to a new instance *each* time:

```
For k = 1 To 10
    Dim temp As cls
    Set temp = New cls
    temp.SetName CStr(k)
    col.Add temp
Next k
```